# Making Havdalah when one didn't have the mizva of shabbat

Tags: shabbat, havdalah

Does a minor who becomes bar mitzva on a Sunday have to make havdala?
He technically didn't keep shabbat so he has nothing to separate from.

Comment: How about if he becomes bar mitzvah on Monday or Tuesday?

Comment: Same difference. I chose Sunday for the proximity to shabbat

Comment: No it's more interesting, because you could imagine that hearing it on Sunday as a katan wouldn't count and he'd have to make it again

Comment: Very well then. I await a response

Comment: https://din.org.il/2017/11/17/%D7%A0%D7%A2%D7%A9%D7%94-%D7%91%D7%A8-%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%94-%D7%91%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%90%D7%99-%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%AA-%D7%9C%D7%94%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%99%D7%90-%D7%90%D7%97%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%99/

Comment: @shmosel that answers it. Thanks